# Need button to float to bottom of card pug/css

Tags: css, formatting, pug

I have a card with text, an image, and a contact button. I need the button to float to the bottom of the card regardless of how much text is in each card so all cards have a uniform contact button in the bottom position.

How one currently looks:
[image]

pug code:

```
   .column.is-one-third
        .card
          img(src='../images/results.png', class="teamImage")
          .h3.is-3.title John Doe
          .p.title Director
          .p Synth polaroid bitters chillwave pickled. Vegan disrupt tousled,
            |Portland keffiyeh aesthetic food truck sriracha cornhole singleorigin
            |coffee church-key roof party. Leggings ethical
            |McSweeney's, normcore you probably haven't heard of them
            |Marfa organic squid.
          .button Contact
```

css:

```
.card {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(10, 10, 
  10, 0.1);
  color: #404040;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative; }

.button {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(5, 71, 168);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```
.card {
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
}

.button {
margin-top:auto;
}
```

```css
.card {
  width:33%;
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:90vh;
  border:1px solid red;
 
}

.button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, voluptatum?</p>
  <button class="button">button</button>
</div>
```